# Send HEX command and read back to rfid reader tcp

Tags: python-3.x

I have a rfid reader that receive that from serial and TCP. I was having one accepting XML data before as command, but this reader only accept HEX command

I'm using python, I'm not sure how to format the data, I'm able to connect with that script, but no sending nor answer, only a timeout of the remote connection.

Here the documentation of the reader: http://www.chafon.com/Upload/ProductFile/CF-RU5106_160719140435.pdf

Here's my code:

```
import socket,time,sys


TCP_IP = '192.168.0.238'
TCP_PORT = 7086
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

MESSAGE = b'0x02'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
except:
    print ('failed ' + TCP_IP + ' down')
    sys.exit()

s.sendall(MESSAGE)

while data is None:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print ("No data, waiting....")
    time.sleep(0.5)

print ("Data arrived")
incoming = data.decode('utf-8')
print (incoming)

s.close()
```